# Make [vista] a synonnym of [windows-vista] and merge the two

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, merge

There are two tags

- **vista** with 29 questions
- **windows-vista** with just 5

I know it is not much significant , but a cleanup is never bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've merged [vista](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/vista) into [windows-vista](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-vista) so that it matches the other windows* tags.

Comment: great thanks for listening !